# Importing a KML file to Google Maps with api call/request

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have geographical data which is represented by a set of points (latitudes and longitudes which form lines), the data is in json. I want to create a Google Map on my website with that data, but the map should also be editable by the user, so he can move the lines, add markers etc.

1. I could create it using the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) - with it I can draw polylines, add markers but everything has to be done by my javascript which adds a lot of work.
2. [Google Maps](https://maps.google.com/) offers a regular user a really nice map editor. To create a map with it the user has to click through the interface or import a KML file.

What I was thinking about, was mixing methods 1. and 2. like this:
 a) Export my data to a KML file
 b) Import the KML file to a users Google Maps account
 c) The user can edit the map with the awesome Google Maps editor
 d) Embed the map back on my website with embed code

The problem is with point b) - **is it possible to import a KML file to Google Maps using some request/api call?**

Answer (score 0):

if you mean on android, yes you can call googlemaps app as an intent from your app and supply a kml file for it to show.

```
String kmlWebAddress = "http://www.afischer-online.de/sos/AFTrack/tracks/e1/01.24.Soltau2Wietzendorf.kml";
String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:0,0?q=%s",kmlWebAddress);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
startActivity(intent);
```

if you mean online, then you can do so by calling googlemaps and appending `"?q=http://www.yourdomain.com/yourfile.kml"`.

like this:

[www.googlemaps.com?q=http://www.afischer-online.de/sos/AFTrack/tracks/e1/01.24.Soltau2Wietzendorf.kml](http://www.googlemaps.com?q=http://www.afischer-online.de/sos/AFTrack/tracks/e1/01.24.Soltau2Wietzendorf.kml)

Comment: Well displaying works but I want to get the map imported into a users Google Maps profile, so he can modify the map himself.

Comment: i wouldnt waste any time writing code to interface with google accounts directly, unless i could guarantee that i would have maintenance man hours available.  google tends to change its protocols, procedures and commercial policies without prior notice (its in the fine print when you use google api's).  besides, IMO it is generally safer to let the user herself decide what they import or not into their google accounts.